# Old site in Magento 1 (1.9.2.3 probably) no longer displaying properly

Tags: magento, backup, restore

Good evening friends,

I've lost contact with my developer years ago and kept running the same M1 backup i had from 2017 whenever something stopped working.
However, now that fails too, even if i erase everything and put the 2017 backup or load a backup from when the site worked, it doesn't load anymore. Please be kind and share some thoughts so that i can restore the backup i have and have it run until i manage to build the new site.
[www.casafoca.ro](https://www.casafoca.ro)

current errors are visible since i edited the sample.xml in errors to show them:
**There has been an error processing your request
The PDO extension is required for this adapter but the extension is not loaded**

Trace:
#0 /home/drapajer/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(248): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->setFetchMode(2)
#1 /home/drapajer/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(175): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->__construct(Array)
#2 /home/drapajer/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(110): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->_newConnection('pdo_mysql', Array)
#3 /home/drapajer/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getConnection('core_write')
#4 /home/drapajer/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(350): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getConnection('write')
#5 /home/drapajer/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(335): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getWriteAdapter()
#6 /home/drapajer/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(360): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getReadAdapter()
#7 /home/drapajer/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(134): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->getReadConnection()
#8 /home/drapajer/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1348): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->__construct(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#9 /home/drapajer/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1380): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('core_resource/w...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#10 /home/drapajer/public_html/app/Mage.php(491): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getResourceModelInstance('core/website_co...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#11 /home/drapajer/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(208): Mage::getResourceModel('core/website_co...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#12 /home/drapajer/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(213): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getResourceCollection()
#13 /home/drapajer/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(619): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getCollection()
#14 /home/drapajer/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(477): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initStores()
#15 /home/drapajer/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(360): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initCurrentStore('', 'store')
#16 /home/drapajer/public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#17 /home/drapajer/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#18 {main}

Thank you very much,
Have a good night
Kind regards
Horace
p.s. feel free to drop me a whatsapp @ +40722600887 if you like

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with the server, not the actual website.
Try contacting your hosting provider and ask them to install/enable PDO on the server.

Edit:

You can run `php -m` to see all active PHP modules. In the resulting list, you'll want to see **pdo_mysql**, but I'm guessing you won't.

Just to be safe, you could try to install the PHP module :
`apt-get install php7.2-common php7.2-mysql` or `sudo apt-get install php7.2-common php7.2-mysql`. If the response says *php7.2-mysql is already the newest version*, then more debugging is necessary as you probably have some conflicting configs.

Otherwise, there is a good chance this will fix your issue.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i did contact them and they said they didn't change anything on the PhP.  I had a look, i have PhP Version 7.2 installed with these checks in place : pdo <--- so it's active pdo_dblib pdo_firebird pdo_mysql pdo_oci pdo_odbc pdo_pgsql pdo_sqlite pdo_sqlsrv So i checked the rest as well. The error persists even if i set PHP Version to 5.3 / 5.4 / 5.5 / 5.6 / 7.0 / 7.1 up to 7.2 which is current.

Comment: Can you run commands on the server terminal ?

Comment: Hi Marian, yes i have SSH access. I'll try to reinstate it. I have no default php.ini though. What commands should i run after i put putty up again? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hey, I've edited the response. If you don't have root access to the server and can't install anything, you'll still need you hosting provider's help.

Comment: Thank you for the help, i managed to restore Php to 5.4 Native, which was better than other versions and now the site is functional again. Since i have everything in Cpanel, it's always up to me to decipher it but for now it works. Thanks again!